# How to bypass "your connection is not Private" in my IONIC app inappbrowser?

Tags: cordova, google-chrome, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

I face a strange problem. Try to open web link in my app inappbrowser or in chrome it show "your connection is not Private".

[image]

Because of that problem My app stuck. Please help me how to bypass this problem and able to open a Link in my app inappbrowser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that the certificate of your site is not issued from a valid authority. I opened that URL on Chrome on windows and it opened correctly. But on the Android browser, it shows the same error you described. 
This means that the authority issued the certificated is not reconized on Android.

Inspecting the certificate shows that the CA is GeoTrust EV SSL

[image]

There is this answer on stackoverflow for the same issue.
[GeoTrust SSL certificate on Android not trusted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22386585/geotrust-ssl-certificate-on-android-not-trusted)

So, all you need is to install GeoTrust intermediate CA, check this link
https://knowledge.geotrust.com/support/knowledge-base/index?page=content&id=AR1421

Comment: There is any solution to bypass that problem in cordova inappbrowser

Comment: I think you need to accept the CA from the android code itself, not from the ionic part. See this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745550/android-how-to-accept-ca-certificate?rq=1